# Is 'sin ser' synonymous with 'sin estar'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, verbos, cópulas

While I'm well aware of when to use *ser* versus when to use *estar*, I'm not so sure if the same rules apply to 'sin ser' and 'sin estar'.

According to [WordReference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=sin%20ser):

> **sin ser** = without being, although not

It also gives an example of usage:

> La reunión, **sin ser** urgente, es necesaria para prevenir problemas. |
>   The meeting, although not urgent, is necessary to prevent problems.

Are *sin ser* and *sin estar* interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, they are not

Even though you are adding "sin" (therefore making it negative) it doesn't change the meaning of the verbs, *ser* is still *ser* and *estar* is still *estar*.

In your example, you couldn't use *estar* as it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Now that you've answered, I feel silly for asking, for now the answer to my question is soooooo obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson as you said this answer is stating the obvious but the differences between _ser_ and _estar_ are not always obvious for the non-native speakers so I think the question is valid and not silly.

Comment: @DGaleano I chose to go straight to the point of the question as it explicitly says: "I'm well aware of when to use *ser* versus when to use *estar*"

Comment: Yes, and that is ok, however we encourage here more elaborate answers. This answer is fine, but so far I like the other answer better but don't feel bad. It is just my **personal preference**, however if you have time and you want, you could improve your answer anytime, and I might change my mind :-)

Comment: No problem, I'll elaborate more next time but I'm a fan of "straight to the point" answers because the difference between *ser* and *estar* has been asked and answered lots of times

Answer (score 2):

**The rules apply.**

There is no difference whether it is in negative or possitive

Lets see the rules

> **Uses of Ser**: 
>        Ser is used to talk about permanent or lasting 
>   attributes. If this general rule is too vague for you, think of the
>   acronym DOCTOR, which stands for Descriptions, Occupations,
>   Characteristics, Time, Origin, and Relationships. Let's take a look at
>   each of the above categories individually.
>
> **Uses of Estar:** 
>        Estar is used to indicate temporary states and
>   locations. If that general rule doesn’t suffice, there are two
>   acronyms that you can think of, PLACE and LoCo. PLACE stands for
>   Position, Location, Action, Condition, and Emotion. LoCo stands for
>   Locations and Conditions. Let's look at PLACE now

[Spanish Dict "ser" vs "estar"](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/ser-vs-estar)

```
La reunión, sin ser urgente, es necesaria para prevenir problemas.
```

**In this case "ser" is used with *time* (for urgent).**

It is not used for location, action, condition or emotions (rules of *estar*) so in this case *estar* can not be used instead of *ser*.

Comment: As the other answer is just stating the obvious I like this answer better.

Comment: This is just the difference between *ser* and *estar*, it says nothing about the negative form, which is what is being asked for

Comment: It makes no difference whether it is in negative or possitive. Why do you see a difference?